# Include organization name in employee's postal address

Tags: contacts, mailing, addresses, address-labels

It's a pretty common scenario -- we'd like to print mailing labels addressed to individuals at their workplaces. For example,

Angela Davis
**UC Santa Cruz**
1156 High Street
Santa Cruz, CA 95064

What is the best practice for doing this in Civi? We could just put the organization name in "Street Address", and move the "real" address lines down into "Supplemental Address" fields. In fact, this is what we do -- but it doesn't seem quite right for a couple reasons:

- In Civi's database schema, the "street_address" column is described as *Concatenation of all routable street address components (prefix, street number, street name, suffix, unit number OR P.O. Box)*. The organization name doesn't seem to belong there, really.
- This is a relational database, so why are we storing the organization name twice (once in the org's own record and once in the employee's address?) There should be a more elegant way to handle this.

Other CRMs include a special "Company" address field, distinct from the "Street Address" field, but again this would be duplicative.

Answer (score 1):

1/ to get Organisation name you should be able to use the token {contact.current_employer} at /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/address?reset=1 (assuming you have them set up with the employee/employer relationship)

2/ if multiple individuals have same Employer address then use the 'share address' feature if you don't already know about that (so

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the organisation addresses already in the database so Pete's answer is probably what you want.

But for completeness for others who might find this question but don't use the employer/employee relationship I will include the following.

We have re-purposed the 'Address name' field to hold company name for the individuals who want to include a company name in their address.  This means that their street address is in the street_address field.  (Our contacts don't have 'Term address' or 'summer address' etc so the original purpose of 'Address name' is not relevant to our system.)